# Is there a name for this simple discrete distribution?

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

I'm just wondering if there's a name for the distribution described by the following p.m.f.:

$$p(n) = n(1-s)^{n-1}s^2$$

where $n$ is an integer from $1$ to $\infty$ and $0\lt s\lt1$.

Comment: I suppose a name matters if you want to learn more about it, but that seems to beg the question: what *do* you want to learn about this distribution?  (Its properties are summarized at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution, by the way.)

Comment: It arose "naturally" from some research and just wondering if there's anything already out there because it seems fairly simple, otherwise I'll just have to do everything from scratch. 
I guess a name doesn't really matter at the end of the day. Thanks!